# Fast controlled copy from istream to ostream

Tags: c++, iterator, stream, iostream

I have to copy several bytes from a `istream` to a `ostream`, there are 2 ways that I know to perform this copy.

```
myostream << myistream.rdbuf();
```

and

```
copy( istreambuf_iterator<char>(myistream),
      istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
      ostreambuf_iterator<char>(myostream)
);
```

I've found that `rdbuf` version is at least twice as fast as the `copy`.
I haven't found yet the way of copying just, say 100 bytes, but as the size to be copied will probably be quite big I would like to be able to use the `rdbuf` version if posible.

How to limit those copies to a given number of bytes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you use 0x?  If so, then you can use copy_n:

```
copy_n( istreambuf_iterator<char>(myistream),
        100,
        ostreambuf_iterator<char>(myostream)
);
```

**EDIT 1:**

I know you're probably looking for a library solution, and you could probably have figured this out on your own.  But in case you haven't thought of something like this, here's what I would do(if I didn't have copy_n):

```
void stream_copy_n(std::istream & in, std::size_t count, std::ostream & out)
{
    const std::size_t buffer_size = 4096;
    char buffer[buffer_size];
    while(count > buffer_size)
    {
        in.read(buffer, buffer_size);
        out.write(buffer, buffer_size);
        count -= buffer_size;
    }

    in.read(buffer, count);
    out.write(buffer, count);
}
```

Comment: I wish I could, not for the moment though!

Comment: Note that the `copy_n` variant copies `n` items, but only removes `n-1` items from the input stream! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bf783061b54bc35