# How to copy a prefix of an input stream to a different stream in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, file, file-io, stream

There's a neat trick that can be used to copy file contents in C++. If we have an `std::ifstream input;` for one file and an `std::ofstream output;` for a second file, the contents of `input` can be copied to `output` like this:

```cpp
output << input.rdbuf();
```

This solution copies the entirety of the first file (or at least the entirety of the `input` stream that hasn't been consumed yet). My question is, **how can I copy only a prefix (`n` first bytes) of an input stream to an output stream?**

After looking through [a bit of documentation](https://cppreference.com), my idea was to somehow shorten the stream of the input and then copy it to the output stream:

```cpp
input.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(input.rdbuf()->eback(), length_to_output);
output << input.rdbuf();
```

The problem is, that this won't compile as `eback` is not `public`. This is only supposed to illustrate my idea. I know that I could just copy the entire input into a string and then copy a substring of it into the output, but I am worried that it will be less time- and memory-efficient. As such, I thought about using streams instead, like above.

Comment: What does "part of the input stream" mean? Some initial portion? Some trailing portion? Some portion in the middle? How do you define, precisely, which "part of the input stream" gets copied?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I meant the `n` first bytes of a stream. I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried different solutions, including the one presented by @Some programmer dude, and ultimately decided to go with a manual `read` and `write` loop. Below is the code that I used (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063994/12501684), with small modifications) and at the bottom are the benchmark results:

```cpp
bool stream_copy_n(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out, std::size_t count) noexcept
{
    const std::size_t buffer_size = 256 * 1024; // a bit larger buffer
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(buffer_size); // allocated on heap to avoid stack overflow
    while(count > buffer_size)
    {
        in.read(buffer.get(), buffer_size);
        out.write(buffer.get(), buffer_size);
        count -= buffer_size;
    }

    in.read(buffer.get(), count);
    out.write(buffer.get(), count);

    return in.good() && out.good(); // returns if copy was successful 
}
```

The benchmark results (when copying an entire file 1GB file) acquired using the built in Unix `time` command, `real` time:

| Method | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Linux C function `sendfile` | 0.59 |
| `std::filesystem::copy_file` | 0.60 |
| Unix command `cp` | 0.69 |
| Manual `read` and `write` loop presented above | 0.78 |
| `output << input.rdbuf()` | 0.96 |
| `std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), std::filesystem::file_size(inputFilePath), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(output));` | 3.28 |
| `std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(input), std::filesystem::file_size(inputFilePath), std::ostream_iterator<char>(output));` | 27.37 |

Despite the fact that it is not the fastest, I chose the `read`-`write` loop as it uses stream objects and isn't exclusive to only copying files.

Comment: Depending on how much you want to copy from the file (and the kind of disk used for the source and destination files, if indeed files), you could use threads to read and write different parts in parallel. You could also experiment with different buffer sizes in your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this is a part of a bigger parallel system and this code has to be single-threaded. I experimented with different buffer sizes and found that 256 kilobytes are the optimal size, as above.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to copy the first `length_to_output` bytes of the input stream, you could use an [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and an [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) together with [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n):

```
std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(input),
            length_to_output,
            std::ostream_iterator<char>(output));
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, but I'm afraid this solution is too slow. I benchmarked it (in the case of copying an entire file) against using `rdbuf`, `std::filesystem::copy_file` and `sendfile`. It is about 2 orders of magnitude slower. When copying a 1GB file, it takes `27.08` seconds, while the other methods take about `0.60` seconds.

Comment: @janekb04 Might be more effective to use a stream buffer iterator (like e.g. [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator). The upside to this metod is that it copies only the amount of bytes you need, not a whole file (which can almost always be done very effectively). The only other solution is to use plain [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

Comment: `std::istreambuf_iterator` is indeed faster - it takes about `3.28` seconds - but that's still way slower than the other solutions. I guess I will have to try `read`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4063994/12501684